# Equivalence of short exact sequences

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

[image: Abstract Algebra, Dummit and Foote, Third Edition, Chapter 3]

The above image is from the book of Dummit and Foote, Edition 3.  In the fourth paragraph, the authors claim that "equivalences involving the same extension module $ B $ are automorphisms of   $  B $ that restrict to identity map on both $ \psi (A) $ and $ B / \psi(A) $".

My question is what claim the authors are trying to make? If the claim is that if we have two short exact sequences,

$$     0    \longrightarrow  A      \stackrel{\psi}{     \longrightarrow}       B   \stackrel{ \phi_{1} } { \longrightarrow  }   C                         \longrightarrow  0     $$

$$     0    \longrightarrow  A      \stackrel{\psi}{     \longrightarrow}       B   \stackrel{ \phi_{2} } { \longrightarrow  }   C                         \longrightarrow  0     $$

which are equivalent to each other, then the automorphism $ \beta :   B    \longmapsto B $ must be such that $ \beta( \psi(a)) = \psi(a) $ and $ \beta( b )  + \psi(A)        =  b + \psi(A) $ for all $ b \in B $, then, this wrong unless $  \phi_{1} = \phi_{2} $, since, we have

$$  \beta(b) +  \psi(A) =  b + \psi(A)  \implies  \beta(b) - b \in  \psi(A)     =     \ker \phi_{1}     =     \ker   \phi_{2}        \implies   \phi_{2} ( \beta(b) - b) = 0         \implies  \phi_{1}(b) = \phi_{2}(b)    .    $$

Also, the next sentence doesn't seem to be smoothly connected to the first one. In my opinion, if you delete the first sentence, the text makes perfect sense. So, what did the authors had in mind when they made that claim?

Comment: it means $\beta( \psi(a)) = \psi(a)$ and $\beta( b + \psi(A)) =  b + \psi(A).$ Not $\beta( b )  + \psi(A)= b + \psi(A)$

Comment: Well, what does the "restriction" of $ \beta $ on $ B / \psi(A) $ mean? The function $ \beta $ is a map on $ B $ which fixes $ \psi(A) $, so it "induces" a map   $  \beta '  $ on $ B / \psi(A) $ given by $   \beta ' (b + \psi(A) )    =   \beta(b) + \psi(A)    $. If this induced map is claimed to be identity, then, this is just what I wrote above.

Comment: start from the identity map $C \rightarrow C.$ let $x \in C.$ then there exist $b, b' \in B$ such that $\phi_1(b) = x = \phi_2(b').$ Also there exists $b'' \in B$ such that $b' = \beta(b'').$ so identity map is saying that $\phi_1(b) + \psi(A) = \phi_2(\beta(b'')) + \psi(A).$

Comment: If that was the intended meaning, I would say it was a very poor choice of words.